# Allocate disk space to another physical drive

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have 2 physical drives in one machine, 128GB SSD designated as C: (Windows 10 drive) and 1TB HDD as D for my data files. Problem is I am lacking disk space in C (1-2 GB remaining) even if I already did disk cleanup and disk compression. So I started to think if it is possible to share some space of my 1TB (D:) to 128GB (C:) drive. How to do it?

Comment: No, not possible. Not without a specific RAID mode anyway.

Comment: You can point any of your user accounts documents folders to be on your 1TB HDD. You can also move your Steam library to another drive if you have that.

Comment: @jdwolf, great idea, will point my C:\Users\<MyAccountName> worth of 7GB to 1TB HDD, gonna search on how to do this. Thanks